# IIS 7 FTP access server via ISP's static IP

Tags: ftp, iis-7

I have a FTP server setup. I can access the site on the local network via a local IP address.
If I am outside the local network I can use the static IP address provided by the ISP.

I need to be able to use the same address to access this server in both places.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the external IP while inside the network, exactly as if you were outside of the network.

Comment: yeah I know... but it doesn't work. why?

Comment: Oh - I didn't get that from the question.  You can access everything correctly from outside the network using the external IP, but not inside the network?  Have you used the same device to access the ftp server inside the network with a local IP, outside the network with the external IP, and attempted to access the server (and failed) with the external IP?  I want to rule out some problem that's local to a machine, like a machine inside the network not being able to use the external IP at all.

Comment: Some more details: I'm actually using the ftp server to try and acess itself... I will try another machine on the local network. Suffice to say the server can acess itself via the local ip but not the external ip. I will try another machine.

Comment: Actually we've tried using the external address on an iphone on the local network with no luck.

Comment: Very strange.  You've confirmed that the iPhone can access the ftp server from outside the network?

Comment: Yes my iphone app can reach the ftp server just fine. It's just when we're on the network (whether app/computer) we have to use the local ip instead of the external.